# WordPress Contact form 7 form field hiding when data is null

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have using contact form 7 plugin in my website. I want to display the mailed data on WordPress dashboard. for getting this i have using a plugin called "Contact Form CFDB7". My form have drop down fields. its showing with conditions. (example one field is country and another field is states, so if selecting the country as US, then the state field only listing US states. this is taken by using the plugin"contact form 7 conditional fields."). so while sending the mail, its will list out all data in dashboard .its have empty fields as well as filled fields. so my question is any option to only show the filled fields in dashboard.

please help me for resolving the same.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a filter that you could use to remove empty values before the form data is saved to the database.

The [`cfdb7_before_save_data`](https://github.com/arshidkv12/contact-form-cfdb7/blob/master/contact-form-cfdb-7.php#L111) filter should do the trick.

This is untested but it should work. You can also swap out the loop and use something like `array_filter()` to clean up the code a bit. Also, remove the return type hint if your not using PHP 7+.

```
/**
 * Removes null values and empty strings from form data before it's saved
 * into the database.
 *
 * @link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087192/wordpress-contact-form-7-form-field-hiding-when-data-is-null
 *
 * @param  array $form_data
 *
 * @return array $form_data 
 */
add_filter( 'cfdb7_before_save_data', function ( array $form_data ): array {

    foreach ( $form_data as $key => $value ) {
        if ( null === $value || '' === $value ) {
            unset( $form_data[ $key ] );
        }
    }

    return $form_data;
} );
```

This snippet will work with older versions of PHP. You can place this at the bottom of your functions.php.

```
/**
 * Removes null values and empty strings from form data before it's saved
 * into the database.
 *
 * @link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087192/wordpress-contact-form-7-form-field-hiding-when-data-is-null
 *
 * @param  array $form_data
 *
 * @return array $form_data
 */
function prefix_or_namespace_filter_cfdb7_before_save_data( array $form_data ) {

    foreach ( $form_data as $key => $value ) {
        if ( null === $value || '' === $value ) {
            unset( $form_data[ $key ] );
        }
    }

    return $form_data;
}

add_filter( 'cfdb7_before_save_data', 'themeprefix_filter_cfdb7_before_save_data', 999 );
```

If your still receiving an error with this please provide screenshots of the error message or open your PHP or WordPress error log and copy the error from there.

Comment: Hi @joe Dooley. 
Thank you for your information. Where we can add this snipet? I have tested within the functions.php file and the website is not loading while adding it.

Comment: Hi @abu. Do you know what version of PHP your server is running? If it's less than 7+ the code snippet will throw an error. I have revised the snippet to support earlier versions of PHP.

Let me know if that solves the problem. And if it doesn't can you screenshot the error that your getting? Or open up your PHP or WordPress error log to tell me what the error is. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @joe Dooley
I have tested the above code in functions.php
Then the mail functionality is working. but in dashboard don't shows the mailed data. i mean its blank.
Please check my screenshot
My PHP version is : https://www.screencast.com/t/cHaqPjJid .
Plugin Dashboard view after adding the above code: https://www.screencast.com/t/c6cuEB1Rt1

Please let me know the issue.

Comment: I have added the back end screenshot of the plugin and facing issue. please check the link for understanding my issue.
https://www.screencast.com/t/hTK4D4eaT